# wso2 issues using call mediator on magento2 api

Tags: wso2, magento2

I'm trying to create a service chain using a wso2 sequence with a payload factory and call mediator.

I'm using wso2 3.2.0 and Magento 2.4.1.
My goal is to ask Magento a token using admin credentials, and returning the token to the client. The payload to make the request should be defined inside the sequence, and there should also be other call mediators after the first one.
I've defined my API with the following definition, and I'm using **dynamic endpoints**

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Magento
  version: v1
servers:
  - url: /
security:
  - default: []
paths:
  /call:
    get:
      parameters: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ok
      security:
        - default: []
      x-auth-type: None
      x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
      x-wso2-application-security:
        security-types:
          - oauth2
        optional: false
    post:
      parameters: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: ok
      security:
        - default: []
      x-auth-type: None
      x-throttling-tier: Unlimited
      x-wso2-application-security:
        security-types:
          - oauth2
        optional: false
components:
  securitySchemes:
    default:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        implicit:
          authorizationUrl: 'https://test.com'
          scopes: {}
x-wso2-cors:
  corsConfigurationEnabled: false
  accessControlAllowOrigins:
    - '*'
  accessControlAllowCredentials: false
  accessControlAllowHeaders:
    - authorization
    - Access-Control-Allow-Origin
    - Content-Type
    - SOAPAction
    - apikey
    - testKey
  accessControlAllowMethods:
    - GET
    - PUT
    - POST
    - DELETE
    - PATCH
    - OPTIONS
x-wso2-production-endpoints:
  type: default
x-wso2-sandbox-endpoints:
  type: default
x-wso2-basePath: /magento/v1
x-wso2-transports:
  - http
  - https
x-wso2-response-cache:
  enabled: false
  cacheTimeoutInSeconds: 300
```

The sequence for my API looks like so,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="service_chain_request_magento" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
    <property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>{"username":"<username>","password":"<pwd>"}</format>
        <args/>
    </payloadFactory>
    <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
    <call blocking="true">
        <endpoint>
            <http method="post" uri-template="http://<magento_ip>/index.php/rest/all/V1/integration/admin/token">
                <timeout>
                    <duration>6000</duration>
                    <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
                </timeout>
            </http>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
    <enrich>
       <source type="body" clone="true"/>
       <target type="property" action="child" property="body_of_first_call"/>
    </enrich>
    <log level="full"/>
</sequence>
```

Where everything inside `<>` is, of course, replaced with proper values.

When I try to call my API `POST - https://<ip>:8243/magento/v1/call` using this sequence, I get the following result:

```
{
"message": "One or more input exceptions have occurred.",
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
      "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "username"
      }
    },
    {
      "message": "\"%fieldName\" is required. Enter and try again.",
      "parameters": {
        "fieldName": "password"
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

even though, inspecting the logs, this is the response:

```
INFO - LogMediator {api:admin--Magento:vv1} To: http://<magento_ip>/index.php/rest/all/V1/integration/admin/token, MessageID: c6b5eb10-89a1-42df-9f0d-098d605dae91, correlation_id: c6b5eb10-89a1-42df-9f0d-098d605dae91, Direction: request, Payload: "brni5ub8o4vfltfups9swrwk3biw3cd4"
```

As what I can understand, the `Payload` field is correctly returning the expected response from Magento rest APIs, but it looks like the REST client I'm using (both Postman and the wso2 console) are returning the error response from the API, like the request is made a second time without the post body.

If I replace the `call` mediator with the `To` header like this:

```
<header name="To" scope="default" value="http://<magento_ip>/index.php/rest/all/V1/integration/admin/token"/>
```

the call just works and returns the expected payload, but then I cannot chain other call mediators.

Here's the specs about the Magento API I'm calling https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.2-admin/tag/integrationadmintoken

How can I resolve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe that your requirement is to generate a token via the Mediation Sequence and to pass that to the actual Endpoint, and correct if my understanding is wrong. Have you looked into this [oauth2 protected endpoint](https://athiththan11.medium.com/wso2-api-manager-oauth2-protected-endpoint-aa51c62f0ad7)? This might help you to achieve what you are trying and the mediation sequence presented in that blog requires few mods to align with yours.

Comment: No, my requirement is to generate a token from Magento APIs, and to return it as the response of my call.
The reason why I'm using a call mediator is because actually I want to do more calls after obtaining the token from Magento, using that token.

Comment: I suspect that you have also configured the API Endpoint with the `Megento Token Endpoint`. If that is the case, from the Mediation sequence, you are calling the Token Endpoint with the Payload, and again the API is sent to the actual configured Endpoint and returned with the error response. You can simply add a `<respond />` mediator after the `call` mediator verify the behavior. Further, you can also update the actual Production & Sandbox endpoint to some other than the Token Endpoint and try-out the scenario

Comment: @Athiththan thank for the suggestion. I'll try that for sure and let you know.

Comment: @Athiththan Ok so I did some tests.
First I added the `<respond />` at the end of the call.
Then I tried switching from dynamic endpoints to HTTP/Rest endpoints with `google.com` as endpoints. Everything works fine as you said, so thank you.
Then I tried switching back to dynamic endpoints, keeping the respond mediator, everything still works.
With dynamic endpoints, I then removed the respond mediator. The issue happens as before, just like the request is sent 2 times, even though the endpoints are dynamic, the latest endpoints were `google`, and I didn't make the request twice.

Comment: So, the API that you have created is using a Dynamic Endpoint is it? and not the HTTP/ REST Endpoint, correct me if wrong. Can you update the question with the current complete sequence that you have in your environment?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question with the API definition and specifying that I'm using dynamic endpoints.
The sequence is the one **before** your correction with the `<respond/ >` mediator.
Adding the respond mediator at the end makes it work, but without even dynamic endpoints give me that error result.